# Why might Graphics.RotateTransform() not be applied?

Tags: c#, graphics, rotatetransform

I have the following function:

```
static private Image CropRotate(Image wholeImage, Rectangle cropArea)
{
    Bitmap cropped = new Bitmap(cropArea.Width, cropArea.Height);

    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(cropped))
    {
        g.DrawImage(wholeImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, cropArea.Width, cropArea.Height), cropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        g.RotateTransform(180f);
    }
    return cropped as Image;
}
```

It's supposed to crop an image, then rotate the resulting sub-image. In actuality though, it only performs the crop.

Why is `RotateTransform()` not being applied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried putting the `RotateTransform()` before the `DrawImage()`? 
The [example on the msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662.aspx) shows the transformation being applied before any drawing is done.

Comment: Bizarrely, this results in a blank image.

Comment: I'm just guessing on this one, but where is the rotation origin for the image? If it is at (0,0), a blank image would be correct. You'll need to set the origin to (cropped.Width/2, cropped.Height/2)

Comment: I assume I'd do this by setting g.RenderingOrigin, but I still get a blank image. Any other ideas?

Comment: That RenderingOrigin actually doesn't have to do with what you're doing. What you need to do is do a g.TranslateTransform() before or after you rotate to reposition the image. It's hard to say which amounts to use without having an example at hand, but I'd do 1. transform(width, height) and 2. rotate

Answer (score 4):

The `RotateTransform` call alters the current transform matrix, which has an effect on all *subsequent* operations.  It does **not** transform the already output operations at all.  This is the same for any of the operations that change the transform matrix (like `ScaleTransform`).

Make sure you call these *before* you perform the operations you want transformed - in this case, before the call to `DrawImage`.

You can use this to do something like

1. Draw (not rotated or scaled)
2. Rotate (only changes transform matrix)
3. Scale (only changes transform matrix)
4. Draw (now rotated and scaled)
5. ClearTransform  (only changes transform matrix)
6. Draw  (not rotated or scaled)

the first and last draw outputs will not be transformed, but the middle one would be affected by both the rotate and scale (in that order).